# Why is the House of Lords retained in a modern democracy?

Tags: united-kingdom, democracy

Members of the House of Lords are unelected, hold their position for life, and citizens cannot remove them in any way. Leaving aside the financial aspect in maintaining this institution, the unelected members exercising supervisory powers seem to be anti-democratic in the first look. Why is this institution continuing as a component of a democracy?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the "House of Lords considered a component of modern democracy"? I am not very familiar with the UK politics, but it seems more complex than a simple "modern democracy": a constitutional monarchy + parliamentary democracy.

Comment: My understanding was wrong. U.K is a constitutional monarchy. House of Lords seems so undemocratic that this question was posted. I Will delete the question if it does not make sense.

Comment: There's no need to delete it, labels such as "constitutional monarchy" and "parliamentary democracy" or "constitutional republic" are technical labels that can be used to make points, but that doesn't change the idea that there are generic modern democratic ideals about accountability and conduct that can and should be applied generally despite technical labels.

Comment: @Alexei the UK is a modern country and a functioning democracy. The house of Lords is a component of the UK's system. So the HoL is a component of a modern democracy. Whether is should be, if for example you were creating a new democracy from scratch without the UK's 800+ years of historical momentum is (as I read it) the core of this question.

Comment: @Jontia the UK is not an especially modern country, it is full of unmodernized feudal relics; it is democratic, but not especially so, with a number of structural biases; and power is unnecessarily centralized on the Prime Minister.

Comment: @RBarryYoung there is clearly a semantics problem in the comments here with the silent use of the words necessary, ideal or good in front of the word component.

Comment: @Caleth On the other hand, US Supreme Court Justices are appointed and approved by (somewhat) democratically elected officials. In recent years, the ability to appoint and approve Supreme Court Justices has become an important issue in US electoral politics, with some candidates even pitching lists of potential nominees to voters. At least some members of the House of Lords have not been appointed by elected officials, so I think the comparison is a bit of an overstatement.

Comment: @RBarryYoung "X is a component of a modern democracy" means that at least one modern democracy has X, not that X is required in a modern democracy. You might be thinking of "X is a component of modern democracy"

Comment: @pjc50 the House of Lords has limited power, mostly limited to review of Bills submitted by Parliament.  They can technically reject bills outright, but it almost never happens.  I rather like that many of those that do serve in the HoL do so purely out of a sense of duty, rather than because they sought the role.

Comment: @pjc50 "and power is unnecessarily centralized on the Prime Minister" You mean, unlike the US president?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> Why is this institution continuing as a component of a democracy?

#### Sixteen Reasons

1. The House of Lords has been defanged (with several rounds of reduced powers), denying it a true veto of legislation supported by the House of Commons. It isn't doing much active harm and its economic cost has been trimmed.
2. The proportion of the Lords who are life lords or hold lordships *ex officio* as a result of some clerical or legal office, has grown, and those are less problematic. In some ways they are more akin to the U.S. federal judiciary or the formal role that the government of France provides to ex-Presidents in its system.
3. The House of Lords historically was dominated by the Tories and continues to have a plurality of them, so a major political party finds it in their partisan interest not to abolish it. Also, any attempt to abolish the House of Lords brought by another major party can be tainted as appearing to be a partisan power grab. The Prime Minister can appoint new life lords to rebalance the House of Lords and it is less extremely biased on a partisan basis than it once was, but the norms regarding the acceptable partisan mix of the House of Lords as a result of life lord appointments are unsettled and in flux. "Packing" the House of Lords in one session is disfavored, but "rebalancing" it is considered acceptable to some extent.
4. The abolition of the House of Lords would be a major step towards the disestablishment of the Anglican Church which many conservatives disfavor.
5. Functionally, as a "house of revision" the House of Lords catches inadvertent errors in legislation that the hastier U.S. style legislative process with long bills finally adopted in the dark of the night with little notice does not allow.
6. On some rare occasions, the House of Lords has called out politicians in the House of Commons for enacting legislation that impairs human rights, sometimes securing changes as a result.
7. While the House of Lords collectively, may add only modest value in the decision-making and voting aspect of legislation, the legislative process also benefits from having diverse voices present in the deliberative process that leads to the adoption of legislation, and the House of Lords provides dozens of avenues other than through partisan elected politicians for new voices to be added to that discussion. Even if only 1-5% of House of Lords members at any given time are making meaningful and useful contributions to the deliberative process that are being provided from no other source, those powerful ideas could be beneficial in some critical respect at some point.
8. Prior to the creation of the U.K. Supreme Court, the House of Lords was the pinnacle of the U.K. judicial system (and that of many former Commonwealth colonies in the form of the Privy Council) and that function created value. This is a recent event and the U.K. may want to have a fallback solution to return to if this major constitutional experiment fails to work as planned.
9. It provides a way to assuage the egos of the residual aristocracy of the U.K. at a minor fiscal and policy cost since it is only a house of delay. Abolishing the aristocracy entirely could have led to an anti-democratic revolution and postponed democracy in the U.K. considerably. Preserving it allowed the U.K. to get democracy sooner and with less resistance at the outside, while allowing the power of the lords to be gradually reduced over time.
10. More generally, legitimacy is path dependent. Generally speaking, if something has always been so, and you learned that this was the way that the system worked as a child and came to accept it, and if there is not a break in succession from one political system or regime or set of leaders to another, it will be accepted as legitimate going forward. The House of Lords has met that test without doing great harm.
11. One can also see the House of Lords as a set of "training wheels" for the democratic government in the House of Commons, because its continuous sessions means that there are legislative institutions (as well as the monarchy) in place during interim periods when a new parliament has been elected but not yet organized a government. While this is probably unnecessary now, and while  it isn't obvious what the House of Lords would actually do if the House of Commons failed to reorganize properly following an election, the appearance that there are institutions that aren't disrupted by the election projects an image of stability following elections, as opposed to allowing opportunists to see a momentary power vacuum as the window of opportunity for radical or extralegal change. In this regard, the House of Lords serves of role similar to the largely symbolic legitimacy and continuity affirming process of having Congress count the electoral votes in a U.S. Presidential election.
12. British political and constitutional history is marked and distinguished by avoiding all or nothing approaches. For example, it retained a constitutional monarchy rather than becoming a Republic (after a brief attempt at that left a bad taste in the British collective consciousness in the 17th century, and then in the 18th century with the American Revolution). Rather than granting full independence to its territories and dependencies, the U.K. has reached individual deals with incomplete autonomy for them. Some have their own domestic laws but remain British for foreign affairs and military purposes (the British demonstrated they were willing to go to great length to honor their obligations in the Falklands War), in some like New Zealand, Australia and for the first century, Canada, it retained final judicial review over its courts, and all have kept a Governor-General's position as a representative of the monarchy. It has different arrangements with Scotland, with Northern Ireland, and with Wales. The House of Lords reflects again the British political culture's tolerance for a situation that is neither an absolute republic, nor an absolute oligarchy or monarchy. France abolished the aristocracy with revolutionary consequences. The British have merely whittled away at it, reducing its privileges, rather than absolutely adopting the principle that all persons are created equal and should be equal under the law for all purposes. As the Daily Express newspaper noted in a [January 22, 2020 article](https://www.express.co.uk/news/politics/1232065/house-of-lords-explained-could-the-house-of-lords-be-abolished-lords-block-brexit):

    > Desire to do away with the House of Lords has long existed in British
    > political consciousness and was once accomplished nearly 400 years
    > ago.
    >
    > When Oliver Cromwell came to rule England after the Civil War of the
    > 1640s, he dramatically reduced the House of Lords’ power, and
    > ultimately abolished the upper chamber in 1649.
    >
    > Parliament branded the Lords “useless and dangerous to the people of
    > England” as they abolished it, but it eventually returned with a
    > resurrected monarchy in 1657.
    >
    > Afterwards, the Lords briefly enjoyed an increase in their power, able
    > to vote down legislation until the Parliament Act 1911 removed this
    > right.

    ("Briefly" in this case, meant 254 years, reflecting the British sense of history.)
13. The preservation of the House of Lords is tied into the norm that British legislators protect the country's constitutional traditions that are only entrenched in ordinary legislation, such as the requirement to hold elections at least every five years and a constitutional tradition of protecting civil and human and property rights. While the institution of the House of Lords adds little value in and of itself, the norm of protecting constitutional traditions that protected it has great value and indeed, is really indispensable to, the U.K.'s democracy since it relies on such norms more than almost any other modern democracy. Abolishing the House of Lords could weaken more important aspects of the U.K.'s constitutional order that lack formalistic protections of the kind found in the U.S. Constitution and the constitutions of most other modern democracies and instead rely on this political norm.
14. Since aristocratic positions are legally a form of inheritable property, abolishing the aristocracy, or at least seeming to do so by abolishing its most visible vestige in the House of Lords, could also be perceived as an attack on the inheritable property rights that share of common legal heritage with aristocratic hereditary titles and the perception that one is undermining property rights by doing so could also be politically problematic since protecting property rights is another important quasi-constitutional political norm in British politics.
15. Closely related is that almost any argument for abolishing the House of Lords is simultaneously an argument for abolishing the monarchy, and the monarchy is seen as a valuable institution in the U.K. system as a symbol of the state that is not tied up in partisanship, and as a safeguard in the event of an event that might threaten the existence or legitimacy of the nation such as a dispute over succession to the Prime Ministership or a disaster or military event that disrupts the ordinary operations of government. Constitutional monarchies, in general, have done better at surviving crises than pure Republics. Abolishing the monarchy without broad support could precipitate a constitutional crisis and crisis of legitimacy in the U.K., and abolishing the House of Lords could threaten to hasten such a crisis.
16. In the current statutory arrangement, the House of Lords is the primary institutional barrier stopping the House of Commons from legislating to cancel the next election and just ruling in perpetuity with no elections. This is because there is an exception to the [Parliament Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliament_Acts_1911_and_1949) allowing the Lords to permanently veto any law that could postpone a general election. Arguably, the institutional barrier could be overcome by legislation, just as the House of Commons, in general, has broad authority to reconfigure the House of Lords in general, in a manner reminiscent of the use of the "nuclear option" in the U.S. Senate to abolish the filibuster with only the support of a bare majority of Senators, rather than the two-thirds majority normally needed to change the rules of an institution with continuity of members from one two year "Congress" to the next. But it is a significant speed bump that any effort to do so would have to overcome that could lead to bipartisan opposition that would prevent such a bill from passing in the House of Commons.

#### What Does A Leader In The House of Lords Say?

The Lord Speaker of the House of Lords (who was a member of Margaret Thatcher's Cabinet for 11 years, pointing out another role of the body as a way to pension off and retain the collective wisdom of former political leaders) defended the institution, albeit with some reforms, in a [June 3, 2019 op-ed column in the Guardian newspaper](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2019/jun/03/lords-reforming-abolishing-not-answer):

> Given the Guardian’s reports on the House of Lords, you might expect
> me, in my role as Lord Speaker, to come forward with some blanket
> defence. I do not. As this paper reported at the beginning of the
> year, I am opposed to what I called “passengers” in the Lords who make
> no or very little contribution. They are a minority, but they undo
> much of the good work done by the vast majority.
>
> In the past 12 months the House of Lords has made almost 2,300 changes
> to improve legislation; apart from daily oral questions, peers have
> tabled more than 8,000 written questions and taken part in more than
> 160 debates; while well over 300 peers have been active members of
> select committees which have published more than 150 reports on
> subjects ranging from tuition fees to intergenerational fairness.
>
> Those who argue for the abolition of the second chamber, as Owen Jones
> did last week, need to say how this work would be done. It is not
> enough just to propose more powers for the Commons in a unicameral
> system – this would do little to improve levels of scrutiny when a
> government is returned with a big majority. In those circumstances,
> having a second chamber to ensure legislation does not slip through
> without proper debate and analysis is absolutely essential. Proponents
> of abolition or complete reform also need to explain how the
> legislation necessary to radically change the Lords will get through
> parliament at a time when Brexit dominates the legislative agenda. It
> is politically naive to believe that any government, in present
> circumstances, would embark on such a course.
>
> The Lords itself – not the government – has agreed to take action to
> reduce numbers following the report of the committee I set up under
> the chairmanship of Terry Burns. We want to see the total size of the
> House capped at 600 and fixed terms for new members. Since the Burns
> report was published there have been almost 70 departures from the
> House but there is clearly more to do. As we await the result of the
> Conservative leadership election and the new prime minister we want to
> see the policy of Theresa May, exercising restraint in appointing new
> members to the Lords, continued by her successors. Responding to the
> Burns report, she said: “I intend to continue with the restraint which
> I have exercised to date and, when making appointments, to allocate
> them fairly, bearing in mind the results of the last general election
> and the leadership shown by each party in terms of retirements.”
>
> That is the first time a prime minister has made such a commitment. It
> is in stark contrast to the policy of Tony Blair who appointed 374 new
> peers and David Cameron who appointed a further 245. To date, May has
> appointed 42 new life peers but the resignation honours list beckons.
> It is at this point that prime ministers are tempted to reward rather
> than ask what contribution a person under consideration can make. I
> very much hope that May will continue to follow her excellent policy
> of moderation.
>
> There has been concern over the work of sitting Lords. Both
> Conservative and Labour governments have confirmed that members should
> be allowed to take up part-time jobs, it would be extraordinary in a
> non-salaried House for it to be otherwise. The rules clearly prohibit
> peers acting as paid lobbyists and also require public disclosure of
> sources of income. We have now set up a new conduct committee under
> the chairmanship of Lord Mance, a former deputy president of the
> supreme court. They keep the code of conduct under review and can
> propose any changes which are necessary.
>
> The Guardian survey of participation underlines one further step that
> we should now consider. Many life peers come to the Lords without much
> idea of the contribution they are expected to make. I remember one
> peer who had just been sworn in coming to me to say they had made a
> mistake and had not realised the work that was involved. We could set
> up a system, as is already the case for those who apply to be a
> crossbench peer, where the House of Lords appointments commission
> questions each new candidate on the contribution that he or she would
> make if their appointment was confirmed.
>
> My belief is that a policy of reducing numbers and checking new
> candidates are prepared to make the contribution that most peers
> already make would go a very long way to eliminating the passengers. I
> should also add it is already the case that every member must make a
> declaration that they have undertaken parliamentary work when they
> claim the daily allowance. If there is any question, the independent
> commissioner for standards can investigate.
>
> Of course, I recognise the policy I have set out will not satisfy
> those who want, for example, to elect the second chamber, but perhaps
> they might understand such a move is currently politically
> impractical. However, progress to make the Lords smaller with all
> members making a sensible contribution is within our grasp.

An op-ed in favor of abolishing it from 2020 can be found [here](https://commentcentral.co.uk/in-the-name-of-democracy-abolish-the-house-of-lords/). The Week offered a short [December 18, 2020 pros and cons article](https://commentcentral.co.uk/in-the-name-of-democracy-abolish-the-house-of-lords/) also outlining the status quo. It argues, in favor of retaining it, that:

> The Daily Telegraph’s Peter Oborne argued that the House of Lords
> continues to work remarkably well, throwing out what he calls
> “populist measures introduced by governments determined to bolster
> their right-wing credentials”.
>
> An elected House of Lords would never have the will or the courage to
> stand up against public opinion, he argues, and would deprive the
> public of the judgement of “very valuable” peers, such as retired
> generals, trade union leaders, academics and judges.

#### Commentary

Are these good reasons? Is this the choice I would make if I were king?

Maybe, maybe not. But the point is to recognize that there are some reasons for the status quo and to properly weigh them when deciding to deviate from them.

Comment: I'd add one more: the Lords contains a large number of experts in their fields who are not interested in being politicians, but are in a position to shape legislation and contribute to debates. While experts are routinely invited to appear before parliamentary committees, that's not the same as actually having them in the legislature. An elected house would lose this benefit. Obviously, whether this outweighs the arguments against an appointed house is a matter for debate.

Comment: I'd dispute #15. While monarchy and peerages are linked, I see no incompatibility with removing or reforming the Lords while maintaining the monarchy. Indeed, Australia has an elected upper house, while NZ abolished theirs, while still keeping the Queen as head of state.

Comment: #3: according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Lords), the Conservatives currently hold 262 out of 800 seats (just under 33%). While they are the largest party, I'd argue that that doesn't amount to the Lords being "dominated" by them.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff My renumbering may throw off your comments. My current point $7 goes to your first comment. With regard to the link of monarchy and peerage, they aren't necessarily linked but the logic behind abolishing one applies very clearly to the other, even though inconsistency is possible, so it s perceived as a threat to the monarchy to abolish the House of Lords. With regard to your last point, the bulk of lords lacking a formal affiliation still lean strongly towards the Conservative party in outlook. This tips the balance.

Comment: #14: as far as I'm aware, no-one is talking about abolishing the aristocracy. I don't see how removing the remaining hereditary peers has anything to do with property rights. Do you have a source for this argument?

Comment: Abolishing the House of Lords would be to abolish the most significant legal vestige of the aristocracy and clear the way for its legal abolition. The link between the history of property rights and hereditary peerage is to long to fit in a comment or add to this post, but is routinely taught in law school property law courses.

Comment: Could you provide sources for the arguments that (a) "it's perceived as a threat to the monarchy to abolish the House of Lords", and (b) abolishing the House of Lords would be to clear the way for the legal abolition of the aristocracy? To be clear, I'm not denying that these things _could_ happen; I'm merely suggesting that the overwhelming bulk of the lengthy debates on this subject have focussed on who (if anyone) gets to sit in the upper house - and not about removing the aristocracy or the monarchy. (Hell, this debate has been contentious enough without adding more fuel to the fire!)

Comment: PS: despite all of my comments, there is much to like in this answer!

Comment: "abolishing the House of Lords would be to clear the way for the legal abolition of the aristocracy?" The House of Lords is an institutional political check on abolishing the monarchy. Any attempt to do so would obviously meet fierce resistance there. A bill to do so might prevail (although I could see the Queen refusing to approve such a measure in one fell swoop notwithstanding her general deference to parliament as it is arguably different in kind from other kinds of legislation as they owe their obligations to her personally to a greater extent) but not without a huge fight due to the HoL.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff - Agreed. This point about the HoL being dominated by the Conservatives stood out to me as palpably incorrect. They're the single largest party affiliation, but outnumbered almost 2:1 by their opposition, who frequently band together to inflict defeats on the Conservative government.

Comment: But the question asks why it is considered as part of modern **democracy**. This answer gives practical reasons why it hasn't been abolished, but none of these reasons give any credence to the idea that it is a **democratic** institution.

Comment: @user000001 The body text question is "Why is this institution continuing as a component of a democracy?"

Comment: A lot of these are dubious at best. #5 needs evidence that the HoL is better than the US Senate, #8 no major party is suggesting abolishing the Supreme Court and judges sat in HoL by convention but Lords didn't get to judge, #9 is implausible (abolition leads to revolution!?), #12 is arguably untrue recently: things like reducing hereditary peers, Welsh devolution, the supreme court, fixed-term parliaments etc were constitutional changes introduced with minimal debate, #14 is incorrect (peerages are not property in any meaningful sense: cannot be sold/transferred, etc).

Comment: @StuartF [2017 Tax Bill](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/americas/us-senate-passes-largest-tax-overhaul-in-31-years/988246) had Senate amendments "scribbled in the bill’s margins" it's difficult to think of a worse process than that. Though the back and forth nature of the US congress would presumably have ensured robust debate/defence of these amendments back in the House.

Comment: @Jontia Those amendment came on a conference committee deal which is as usually the case but together in secret, released shortly before the vote on a massive bill, and subject to only minimal floor debate. Most major bills in the U.S. Congress are passed this way.

Comment: @StuartF The ability to sell or transfer real property and to dispose of it by will rather than intestate succession by operation of law were both some of the very last additions to the bundle of rights that came with real property ownership in the U.K.

Comment: @StuartF Restraints on the alienation and devise of land, though the estate in land known as a fee tail which essentially limited transfers of land in the same way that peerages are now limited was not abolished in England until the Settled Land Act of 1882.

Comment: For me #5 is the real point: elected representatives (modulo arguments about how representative they are with first-past-the-post &c) make laws, and some of them execute laws, but appointed representatives scrutinise those laws and suggest revisions.  I personally think it's good that the latter include experts and those who can be more concerned with doing the right thing than the most popularly-appealling thing.  (Not that they all always do, of course, but it removes one major reason why not.)  After all, an adversarial approach works well in the judiciary, software testing,…

Comment: @gidds The point you make is fair. It also illustrates in a manner that many political scientists, especially in the U.S. don't sufficiently recognize, that the bare structure of an institution and the formal legal rights of the parties isn't the only thing that matters. Institutional culture cultivated over the entire history of an institution, matters a lot as well. This can make an institution like the HoL work in a way that analogous institutions do not (e.g. there is a good case that the HoL is more effective as a house of revision than the Canadian Senate).

Answer (score 18):

It is seen as **sufficiently powerless**, in the real scheme of things, to make it a quaint holdover from ancient times. Much like the monarchy. If the Queen would actually exercise all those powers which she *graciously delegates* to the elected representatives of the people, the UK would be a dictatorship. But the Queen knows that she couldn't do that (at least not for long) and she probably doesn't want to do it, either.

Read about the [Crown-in-Parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen-in-Parliament) so see how the UK reconciles the traditional powers of the monarchy with modern times.

The House of Lords actually does wield some powers, but the influence of the hereditary peers is sufficiently diluted by the new, lifetime-only peers to make the tradition acceptable to modern, democratic sensibilities. These peers are chosen by the Queen, *on the advice of the Prime Minister and parliament*. Which is a fancy way of saying, by the elected representatives.

But any honest observer would admit that the House of Lords is not, at the core, a democratic institution.

Comment: To give some numbers, there are now 92 seats for hereditary peers, (with 92 currently filled) and 26 Lords Spiritual (i.e. bishops from established churches, in practice the Church of England) in a house with 800 sitting member. That last figure is also a topic of conversation.

Comment: Re: "it would be a dictatorship", of course not... it would stop being a monarchy way before it came to that. The UK has long past gone from "The Queen delegates her authority" to "Let's all say and pretend she does, it brings in tourists". While she is *de jure* stronger than monarchs in countries like Sweden en Belgium, *de facto* she is not.

Comment: @DonFusili, I think that is just what I was trying to explain. Was that not clear enough?

Comment: @o.m. You're right, I misread that part of the answer, my bad. I'd give you an upvote, but I already did that before commenting earlier ;-)

Comment: "If the Queen would actually exercise all those powers which she graciously delegates to the elected representatives of the people, the UK would be a dictatorship" — see also [Queen's Consent](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/series/queens-consent)

Answer (score 2):

The House of Lords is a house of review. Life peers represent a cross section of society, either appointed by the government of the day, or as hereditary peers. (c.f. juries) Apart from the fact that hereditary peers are generally *perceived* as more conservative on average than the rest of the lords, the system has worked well, as has our monarchy. The Queen is unelected too but enjoys wide support. "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Changes often have unintended consequences. Blair gave Scotland and Wales their own parliament which has probably emboldened their nationalist movements and now threatens the union.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "house of review" for people unfamiliar with the UK system?

Comment: @divibisan The UK parliament has 2 houses: The House of Commons, and the House of Lords. The Commons is where *most* legislation starts.

Comment: @Caleth: no it isn't. Mainly for reasons of scheduling, bills are split between the two houses - and indeed, apart from money bills (which must start in the Commons), it makes little difference which house a bill starts in.

Comment: + who is also not elected yet wields immense actual power? Big corporation who have enormous lobbying power. Multi-billionaires who can pour lots of money into NGOs which promote their views. Social media companies which have already been caught doing psychological manipulation, so they have the means to influence elections. Yet the well-being of the country is in the Queen's best interests, because her position is tied to the country: if the country goes down, she loses her throne, but the aforementioned billionaires could then just take their money elsewhere and not care what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are great, I'd just like to highlight a term lengths matter.

It's very useful in democracies to have a mixture of term limits as it limits the tendency toward landslides, like adding baffles to a water tank to limit sloshing.

You see this in the US with Representatives (2 years), President (4 years), Senators (6 years) and Supreme Court Justices (life (incidentally also not really elected)).

In the UK, having only one elected house and a PM instead of a President loses the separate terms for Senate and President, the House of Lords counter balance this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that Canada has a similar *upper house* in a bicameral legislature.  It has no trappings of *nobility*, but the appointments are for life (though there's a mandatory retirement at age 75).

The Queen of Canada makes the appointments upon recommendation of her government.  In reality, it means that the government of the day gets to make appointments when seats open up.

There is much discussion in Canada about making the Senate more democratic.  The advantage that is has as an appointed (rather than elected) body is that it is pretty toothless.  The House of Commons, being elected, is where power resides.  It is *very* rare that the Senate gets in the way of *the will of the people*.

Compare this to the US where Senators (even from states like Vermont or Wyoming; states with only a single congressperson) are imbued with much more power than congresspeople.  I'm a big fan of a toothless upper house.  It's also worth noting that the "founders" (the folks who drafted the US Constitution) did not plan on an elected Senate.  Until the 17th amendment (in force in 1913), the Senators were chosen by the states.